# User Profile Not Saving Changes

Tags: user-profile

My edit profile page doensn't save all fields:

```twig
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/saveUser">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/users/{{ user.username }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ user.id }}">

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Your Photo</legend>
    {# Check to see if the user has a photo  #}
    {% if currentUser.photoUrl %}

      <figure><img src="{{ currentUser.photoUrl(200) }}" /></figure>
    {# If a photo exists, give the option to change the user photo #}
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="userPhoto" value="Change Photo" class="form-control">
    </div>

    {% else %}

    {# If no photo exists, give the option to upload a new one #}
    <figure><img src="/assets/img/user.gif" /></figure>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="userPhoto" value="Upload" class="form-control">
    </div>
    {% endif %}
  </fieldset>


  <fieldset>
    <legend>Your Login Details</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="fields[email]" value="{{ user.email }}">
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
  <legend>Your Personal Details</legend>
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="fields[firstName}" value="{{ user.firstName }}">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="fields[lastName]" value="{{ user.lastName }}">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="phoneNumber">Contact Number</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" name="fields[phoneNumber]" value="{{ user.phoneNumber}}">
  </div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    {% set pets = craft.fields.getFieldbyHandle('pets') %}

  <legend>Your Property Details</legend>
  <label for="pets">{{ pets.instructions }}</label>
  <select class="form-control margin-bottom" id="pets" name="fields[pets]">
    {% for option in user.pets.options %}
    <option {% if option.selected %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ option }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>

  {% set renting = craft.fields.getFieldbyHandle('renting') %}

  <label for="renting">{{ renting.instructions }}</label>
  <select class="form-control margin-bottom" id="renting" name="fields[renting]">
    {% for option in user.renting.options %}
    <option {% if option.selected %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ option }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>

  </fieldset>


  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right margin-top" value="Save Profile">
</form>
```

It only saves the last two fields which means that a user can't change their email address, name or phone number.

I've recently updated Craft to the latest build (Craft Pro 2.1.2566) and also changed user/saveProfile to user/saveUser.

Comment: Just corrected it but no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the `value=` attribute on your select fields.

```
<select class="form-control margin-bottom" id="renting" name="fields[renting]">
{% for option in user.renting.options %}
<option {% if option.selected %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ option }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

**Should be:**

```
<select class="form-control margin-bottom" id="renting" name="fields[renting]">
{% for option in user.renting.options %}
<option value="{{option.value}}"{% if option.selected %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ option }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

I was looking for the answer to the same problem. I narrowed my issue down to the  field. When I removed it the form would submit properly. I fixed a typo in the value attribute and that fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

`firstName`, `lastName`, and `email` are actual user fields (not custom), so their `name=` attributes shouldn’t have the `fields[]` namespace.

```html
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="{{ user.email }}">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="{{ user.firstName }}">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" value="{{ user.lastName }}">
```

I’m guessing that once you fix those, your `phoneNumber` custom field will also start saving.

Comment: That all works apart from the email field. I'm using the 'useEmailAsUsername' => true, config setting if that changes anything.

Comment: I also have the verify email setting on. Ideally this would only be sent when registering new accounts and not when a user is changing their email.

Comment: @NiallThompson to allow the user to change their email you need to pass a password also I believe.

Comment: @LukeHolder nails it. Since changing the password and/or email of an existing user is "a big deal", you need to pass in the currently logged in user's password in a field named "password" in order for it to work.

Comment: As in a hidden field like this? <input type="hidden" name="password" value="{{ user.password }}">

Comment: @NiallThompson It has to be the  password of the *currently logged in* user.  Not the password for the user you're trying to change the password of.

Comment: @NiallThompson plus, `{{ user.password }}` is going to give you the hashed password, and the `"password"` input needs to be set to the unhashed password. The whole point is, users need to prove that they are who they are before they can change their email address/password.

Answer (score 3):

It should also be noted that to change your password or email, the current password has to be passed along with the request.

```
// You must pass your current password to change these fields for an existing user
```

Answer (score 2):

For starters I see you have a typo...

`fields[firstName}`

Should be

`fields[firstName]`

Also:

`{{ user.phoneNumber}}`

Should be:

`{{ user.phoneNumber }}`

Comment: I've made the changes but the firstName, lastName and email fields won't save still.